# How to call function with dict, while ignoring unexpected keyword arguments?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Something of the following sort. Imagine this case:

```py
def some_function(a, b):
    return a + b
  
some_magical_workaround({"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3})  # returns 3
```

I can't modify `some_function` to add a `**kwargs` parameter. How could I create a wrapper function `some_magical_workaround` which calls `some_function` as shown?

Also, `some_magical_workaround` may be used with other functions, and I don't know beforehand what args are defined in the functions being used.

Comment: Do you mean that you can't modify `some_function` and want to create a wrapper function `some_magical_workaround` which calls `some_function`?

Comment: Add `**kwargs` and actually unpack the dictionary?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yep, I can't modify `some_function`

Comment: anecdotally, you may be interested in decorators, which will accept a function and return a function without changing its name

Comment: Can you show a concrete example of how `some_magical_workaround` will also be used with another function that is different from `some_function`?

Comment: @ti7 Thanks, I thought of them, and was planning on using them eventually

Comment: hmm.. this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) overall .. what are you really trying to do? (for example, why not just change the function signature or pass the right dict members in the caller?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you cannot do this in general if the function isn't written in Python (e.g. many built-ins, functions from third-party libraries written as extensions in C) but you can use the `inpsect` module to introspect the signature. Here is a quick-and-dirty proof-of-concept, I haven't really considered edge-cases, but this should get you going:

```
import inspect

def bind_exact_args(func, kwargs):
    sig = inspect.signature(func) # will fail with functions not written in Python, e.g. many built-ins
    common_keys = sig.parameters.keys() & kwargs.keys()
    return func(**{k:kwargs[k] for k in common_keys})

def some_function(a, b):
    return a + b
```

So, a demonstration:

```
>>> import inspect
>>>
>>> def bind_exact_args(func, kwargs):
...     sig = inspect.signature(func) # will fail with functions not written in Python, e.g. many built-ins
...     return func(**{k:kwargs[k] for k in sig.parameters.keys() & kwargs.keys()})
...
>>> def some_function(a, b):
...     return a + b
...
>>> bind_exact_args(some_function, {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3})
3
```

But note how it can fail with built-ins:

```
>>> bind_exact_args(max, {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in bind_exact_args
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/inspect.py", line 3113, in signature
    return Signature.from_callable(obj, follow_wrapped=follow_wrapped)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/inspect.py", line 2862, in from_callable
    return _signature_from_callable(obj, sigcls=cls,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/inspect.py", line 2329, in _signature_from_callable
    return _signature_from_builtin(sigcls, obj,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/inspect.py", line 2147, in _signature_from_builtin
    raise ValueError("no signature found for builtin {!r}".format(func))
ValueError: no signature found for builtin <built-in function max>
```

As noted in @JamieDoornbos answer, another example that will not work is a function with positional-only paramters:

E.g.:

```
def some_function(a, b, /, c):
    return a + b + c
```

Although, you can introspect this:

```
>>> def some_function(a, b, /, c):
...     return a + b + c
...
>>> sig = inspect.signature(some_function)
>>> sig.parameters['a'].kind
<_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_ONLY: 0>
>>> sig.parameters['b'].kind
<_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_ONLY: 0>
>>> sig.parameters['c'].kind
<_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: 1>
```

If you need to handle this case, it is certainly possible to, but I leave that as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: Thanks! perfect! how to know if a param is **, or *?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module to find out the argument names for the original function and filter your dictionary:

```py
import inspect


def some_function(a, b):
    return a + b


def some_magical_workaround(d):
    args = inspect.getfullargspec(some_function)[0]
    return some_function(**{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k in args})


print(some_magical_workaround({"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}))
```

This will print:

```
3
```

It can even be made more general by making the function itself an argument:

```
def some_magical_workaround(func, d):
    args = inspect.getfullargspec(func)[0]
    ...

print(some_magical_workaround(some_function, {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}))
```

Comment: Great minds think alike :) But just a note, `getfullargspec` is a legacy API, really only kept around to make porting Python 2 to Python 3 easier. It was actually deprecated at some point, although that decision was reversed. But same idea as using `inspect.signature`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I had no idea. I guess I'll leave this answer as it is since your answer already demonstrates the use of the more modern `.signature()` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the entire dict to a wrapper function, you can do so, read the keys internally, and pass them along too

```py
def wrapper_for_some_function(source_dict):
    # two possible choices to get the keys from the dict
    a = source_dict["a"]         # indexing: exactly a or KeyError
    b = source_dict.get("b", 7)  # .get method: 7 if there's no b
    # now pass the values from the dict to the wrapped function
    return some_function(a, b)
```

---

original answer components

If instead, you can unpack the dict, when you define your function, you can add a `**kwargs` argument to eat up unknown args

```py
def some_function(a, b, **kwargs):
    return a + b
```

```py
>>> def some_function(a, b, **kwargs):
...     return a + b
... 
>>> d = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
>>> some_function(**d)       # dictionary unpacking
3
```

Comment: *"`some_magical_workaround` may be used with other functions"* This answer does not support it

Comment: I think they may want a [decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74791708/how-to-call-function-with-dict-while-ignoring-unexpected-keyword-arguments/74791742#comment131995719_74791708), but their Question is evolving

Comment: Since they can't modify `some_function` I'm not sure a decorator is applicable here

Comment: ah, they have fundamentally modified their Question several times and are coming from another programming language, so chat may be better or wait for them to settle what they are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

For basic use cases, you can do something like this:

```
import inspect

def some_magical_workaround(fn, params):
    return fn(**{
        name: value for name, value in params.items()
        if name in set(inspect.getfullargspec(fn)[0])
    })

some_magical_workaround(some_function, {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3})
```

However, be warned that calling functions this way circumvents the explicit coupling of parameters, which is designed to expose errors earlier in the development process.

And there are some constraints on the values of `fn` that will work as expected. `some_function` is fine, but here's an alternative that won't work because the parameters are not allowed to have names:

```
>>> def some_function2(a, b, /):
...    return a+b
...
>>> some_magical_workaround(some_function2, {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in apply_by_name
TypeError: some_function() got some positional-only arguments passed as keyword arguments: 'a, b'
```

Comment: Good thing to note about the positional only parameters!